# Can't remove single handle shower handle

Tags: shower, valve, corrosion

I have a Delta Monitor Multichoice 13/14. Removed the hex screw but handle will still not come off. I tried all kinds of twisting and banging on it. Some people suggested rotating the handle past 180 degrees which i tried with some light force but do not want to break the assembly at the same time. Is there something I'm missing or are the pieces most likely corroded together? I'm assuming they were not glued together.

Answer (score 2):

Confirming from [the fine manual](https://archive.org/details/delta-51975-rev-i) it appears you're on the right track-- remove the set screw then pull.

> [image: Handle assembly]

You may be able to use a faucet puller tool for slightly more leverage.

If there is a buildup of mineral deposit or corrosion you may need to use a chemical to loosen the threads.

Comment: @Tester101, thanks for adding the screenshot.

Comment: is this a common problem? i'm trying to figure out if it's time to give up and break the whole thing off. i've already spent 20 hours on this piece of junk and my tenants and everyone at home depot hate me now.

Comment: Note the link to "the fine manual" is dead.

Comment: Note the hex Allen wrench needed is probably the 3/32" size -- this is very difficult to determine sometimes when the hole is well hidden from view, especially on some designs where the set screw may be some depth into the handle.  This is also not mentioned in any Delta manual I've seen.

Comment: Thanks @GregA.Woods; link to the Fine Manual redirected to the wonderful Archive.org.